# Android: How to change the color of the drawable background of TextView dynamically in the java code

Tags: android

I need to make TextView with rounded background with dynamic color.
I know how to make drawable background but I don't know how to change the color of it in the code?

the drawable bg xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"></solid>
<!-- I want to change this color dynamically in the java code --> 
            <corners android:radius="7dp"></corners>
        </shape>
    </item>


</selector>
```

the textview in the layout xml:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_taskTag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_solid"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:text="work"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
```

in the Java file code:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {  

       holder.txt_taskCategory.setText(holder.mTask._catName);
       holder.txt_taskCategory.setBackgroundColor( Color.parseColor( holder.mTask._catColor));
    //when i do that it remove the drawable background and just color it.


}
```

What i need is to change the color of the drawable background (not the Textview) whith `"holder.mTask._catColor"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this like this:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_rounded_solid);
drawable.mutate().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
yourTextView.setBackground(drawable);
```

This should work (not tested, just from my mind)!
Just reset the drawable once you change the color of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create 2 seperate drawables and switch them accordingly.